# Tensorflow: ValueError: Shapes (None, 24) and (None, 2) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I am trying to write a program which would predict the handwritten text inside a given image. The dataset I am using is found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sachinpatel21/az-handwritten-alphabets-in-csv-format). For my purpose all I need to be predicted is X's and O's and so I created a new dataset using index slicing to only keep instances of X's and O's.

When I try to fit the model I keep getting the following error:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 24) and (None, 2) are incompatible`

I'm not sure what is happening but my assumption is that the way I am reducing the dataset to keep only X's and O's is incorrect and is causing some error. I have tried changing the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and `binary_crossentropy` and I still can't fit the model

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.keras as keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

dataset = pd.read_csv("./A_Z Handwritten Data.csv").astype('float32')
dataset_reduced_o = dataset[139811:197636]
dataset_reduced_x = dataset[349243:355515]
new_dataset = pd.concat([dataset_reduced_o, dataset_reduced_x])
new_dataset = new_dataset.reset_index(drop=True)
new_dataset.rename(columns={'0':'label'}, inplace=True)

# Splite data the X - Our data , and y - the prdict label
X = new_dataset.drop('label',axis = 1)
y = new_dataset['label']

from sklearn.utils import shuffle

X_shuffle = shuffle(X)

# Change label to alphabets
alphabets_mapper = {14:'O',23:'X'} 
dataset_alphabets = new_dataset.copy()
new_dataset['label'] = new_dataset['label'].map(alphabets_mapper)

# splite the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

# scale data
standard_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
standard_scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = standard_scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = standard_scaler.transform(X_test)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)

cls = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
cls.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

cls.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = cls.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3)

scores = cls.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print("CNN Score:",scores[1])
cls.save('handwritten.model')
```

Here is the image of the output when I print my X and y[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

label (y in your code) should be integer type, not char or else.
And label doen't mapped at all.

Change

```
# Change label to alphabets
alphabets_mapper = {14:'O',23:'X'} 
dataset_alphabets = new_dataset.copy()
new_dataset['label'] = new_dataset['label'].map(alphabets_mapper)
```

to

```
# Change label to alphabets
alphabets_mapper = {14:0,23:1} 
dataset_alphabets = new_dataset.copy()
# new_dataset['label'] = new_dataset['label'].map(alphabets_mapper)
y = y.map(alphabets_mapper)
```